# Integration involving d[x] instead of dx

Tags: integration

Find the value of: $$\int_0^3(x^2+1)d\lfloor x\rfloor$$

Shouldn't the answer be zero since $[x]$ is always an integer? But the options given are $12,17,15,19$. ([x] denotes floor(x))

From $0$ to $1$, $[x]=0$ and $d[x]=0$. Similarly, from $1$ to $2$, $[x]=2$ and $d[x]=0$ and so on...

Comment: I got this question from my book. I did not make it. Is it wrong?

Comment: At least you got a non zero answer. How did you solve it?

Comment: Do you know what Lebesgue Stieltjes integration is? (And is $[x]$ the floor or ceiling?)

Comment: No. But I would like to learn it. (And learn how to pronounce it). Let me Google it.

Comment: I didn't understand a thing given in wikipedia. Can you suggest a site?

Comment: Do you know what integration with respect to an arbitrary measure is? How did you encounter this problem?

Comment: No. I can integrate wrt d(sinx). You can simply multiply and divide by dx to get $\frac{d(\sin x)}{dx}$.

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Comment: @copper.hat: what should I learn before learning lebesgue theorem?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1230680/integration-with-respect-to-the-floor-function

Comment: Probably just the Riemann Stiljes integral.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral

Comment: @sujith, this question is slightly different. My question is more basic.

Comment: @AdityaDev Reimann integration is something like applying chain rule and taking limit , there must be some secret manipulation of $x^2+1$ to make it in terms of $\floor{x}$

Comment: @Sujith, I don't see any manipulation.

Comment: @AdityaDev: It is a little more involved that can be conveniently explained in a comment, but it starts with defining a measure (or length) as $\mu_{\lfloor \cdot \rfloor}((a,b]) = \lfloor b \rfloor -  \lfloor a \rfloor$.

Comment: $[x]$ was for a long time the standard notation for "floor (x)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^2+1$, $\alpha(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$, and let $P$ be a partition of $[0,3]$ such that the points $1,2,3$ are in different partitions.

Let $I_k$ be the intervals in the partition and without loss of generality, suppose $k \in I_k$ for $k = 1,2,3$. Note that we have
$\alpha(\sup I_k) - \alpha(\inf I_k) = 1$ for $k=1,2,3$.
Also note that
on any other interval $J$ in the
partition, we have $\alpha(\sup J) - \alpha(\inf J) = 0$.

Hence we have
$L(P,f,\alpha) = \sum_{k=1}^3 \inf_{x \in I_k} f(x)(\alpha(\sup I_k) - \alpha(\inf I_k)) = \sum_{k=1}^3 \inf_{x \in I_k} f(x)$,
and similarly we have
$U(P,f,\alpha) = \sum_{k=1}^3 \sup_{x \in I_k} f(x)$.

Since $k \in I_k$ we see that
$L(P,f,\alpha) \le \sum_{k=1}^3 f(k)$ and similarly 
$U(P,f,\alpha) \ge \sum_{k=1}^3 f(k)$.

Since $f$ is continuous, for any $\epsilon>0$ we can choose a partition so that
$L(P,f,\alpha) \ge \sum_{k=1}^3 f(k)-\epsilon$,
$U(P,f,\alpha) \le \sum_{k=1}^3 f(k)+\epsilon$,
from which it follows that
$\int_0^3 f(x) d \alpha(x) = \sum_{k=1}^3 f(k)$.

Evaluating for the specific $f$ gives $17$.